# insert characters into designated area of string

Tags: ruby, string, include

How would I print my desired output I layout in the comment at the end of my code?

```
string = "matthews"

    # letters = string.split(//)  NOT USING

letter_guess = "t"

if string.include? letter_guess
  print "its there"
else
  print "its not"
end


    # I would then like to ouput this!! --tt----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple if you just substitute for all non-present letters:

```
if (string.include?(letter_guess))
  puts "It's there: %s" % string.tr('^' + letter_guess', '-')
else
  puts "It's not there."
end
```

The [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-tr) method is very good at removing or altering things on a per-character basis. In this case it replaces all letters that do not (`^`) match with `-`.

Comment: awesome.  Thanks!  What if I need to pass that value back into an array of the letters within the string... Like if I had

Comment: awesome. Thanks.  What if I need that value to be passed back into an array of the same length as the string that is made up of "-" characters?  Rather than pass it directly to a string... so if it were string = "great" and the letter was r, it would print ["-", "r", "-", "-", "-"]

Comment: @RobMatthews Given any string you can easily extract the characters from it: `s.chars`